# c# - Splitting a string, then writing into datagridview rows

Tags: c#

I have a serialport which reads a string such as: "11,22,33,44", however the number of separators differ etc: "11,22,33,44,55,66"

I want to split the string and then write the separated strings into a datagridview, I have tried:

```
string[] array = _text.Split(',');
table.Rows.Add(array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
datagridview1.DataSource = table;
```

However, the problem here is that the arrays may come in a different amount. 
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add each item as a parameter to `Add`.  The [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56.aspx) method takes an array as the parameter, so you can just do:

```
string[] array = _text.Split(',');
table.Rows.Add(array);
datagridview1.DataSource = table;
```

And it will add columns corresponding to the number of items in your array.

If you want to add *multiple* rows with a varying number of columns, you will need to check the size of the array first, then add columns to the `DataTable` as necessary, otherwise you will get an exception if the number of items in the array exceeds the number of columns in the `DataTable`.

Comment: Thanks! My problem for me was i did table.Rows.Add(i++, array); where "i" was an integer for index. What happened was it displayed "System.String[]" in the table cell.

Comment: using foreach , you can do this easily than for.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is iterate over array and add each item.

```
string[] array = _text.Split(',');
foreach(var item in array)
{
     table.Rows.Add(item);
}
datagridview1.DataSource = table;
```

Answer (score 0):

For do this you can parse into string list..

```
_text = "11,22,33,44,55,66";

List<String> str_list = new List<String>();
str_list = _text.Split(',').ToList();
foreach(var item in str_list)
{
    table.Rows.Add(item);
}
datagridview1.DataSource = table;
```

This will work for you..

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add the array as the row to the `DataGridView`, check the below code snippet.

```
namespace SO
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            var input = "11,22,33,44";
            string[] array = input.Split(',');
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(array);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]